# How can I create a random number between two numbers in Perl

Tags: perl

I've seen many other ways to do this in other programming languages... Though I havent found one in Perl yet...

What I want to accomplish is to set two numbers:

```
$minimum = 100;
$maximum = 4000;
```

Then to create a random integer between those two.  (whole number)
($random_num)

I've looked into this site: http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/rand_function.html

Which is a good resource, although does not do exactly that.

Comment: Integer or floating point?

Comment: @dvnrrs Integer, Sorry, I'll edit the question to include that

Comment: perl has good documentation; check it *before* looking for other random sites: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-get-a-random-number-between-X-and-Y%3F (answer shown by toolic's suggested perldoc command)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
my $x = $minimum + int(rand($maximum - $minimum));
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html

Note this range *excludes* `$maximum` itself. Add 1 to make it inclusive.

Answer (score 5):

```
my $random_num = int($minimum + rand($maximum - $minimum));
```